# New to GWT, Google Code and App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am new in the whole Google code thing.

So my question is the following.

Having downloaded the Google Plugin for eclipse, i have created a new Project, which has automatically created an example code, the Greeting Example.

So I deployed it to the app Engine, an all worked OK. So now i am trying to add some functionality.. Via eclipse, I downloaded the Google Contacts API and transferred the Jars in the classpath as well as in the LIB directory.

So, in the server side of the project, in file GreetingServiceImpl.java I have added the following line

```
        ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService("Contacts");
```

so the file looks like this..

```
package com.gnt.server;

import com.gnt.client.GreetingService;
import com.gnt.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

/**
 * The server side implementation of the RPC service.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GreetingService {

    public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Verify that the input is valid. 
        if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(input)) {
            // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException back to
            // the client.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
        }

        String serverInfo = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
        String userAgent = getThreadLocalRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");

        // Escape data from the client to avoid cross-site script vulnerabilities.
        input = escapeHtml(input);
        userAgent = escapeHtml(userAgent);
            ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService("Contacts");
        return "Hello, " + input + "!<br><br>I am running " + serverInfo
                + ".<br><br>It looks like you are using:<br>" + userAgent;
    }

    /**
     * Escape an html string. Escaping data received from the client helps to
     * prevent cross-site script vulnerabilities.
     * 
     * @param html the html string to escape
     * @return the escaped string
     */
    private String escapeHtml(String html) {
        if (html == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return html.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
                .replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
    }
}
```

Now when i deploy this to the App Engine, i get the following error..

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.gnt.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-ff033622b2cd8d3f(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at com.gnt.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-ff033622b2cd8d3f(Request.java)
    ... 34 more
```

How can this be; The necessary libraries are in the classpath and Lib directory...

I ve been searching for two days now and i have not found any answer...

For Testing purposes, i have added the Apache commons Lib and called a method from that lib and it worked perfectly inside the App Engine.

So what am i doing wrong? How can i use the Contacts API inside App Engine?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the Google Data JARs.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/eclipse) for a tutorial. Make sure that `gdata-client`, `gdata-client-meta`, `gdata-core`, and `gdata-media` JARs are in your build path.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have managed to overcome the problem. Weird that as soon as i put the jars from the example mentioned, the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError disappeared. Even thought the actual Class that was missing was indeed in the lib. Anyway i ll continue reading about OAuth2 procedure since it is required to access the apis.  Again thx for your help!